# pyinstaller выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pyinstaller

C:\python38>pyinstaller -F type.py
  File "C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xec' in file C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: В какой кодировке сохранён код? Попробуйте пересохранить в `UTF-8`, если он не в ней.

Comment: Похоже, что у вас битый скрипт pyinstaller-а. Попробуйте переустановить этот пакет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте исправить кодировку на UTF-8 (через Notepad++) в файле C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py